# why search is not working on jquery-dataTable javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

i have a `table` there i have included a `button` for action , because of that the search is not working on that `table`.

**Here is Demo:**https://jsfiddle.net/pkxmnh2a/33/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#examples').DataTable();
  $('a.toggle-vis').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
    column.visible(!column.visible());
  });

  $('#examples tfoot th').each(function() {
    var title = $('#examples thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
    $(this).html('<input tyepe="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '"/>');
  });
  table.columns().eq(0).each(function(colIdx) {
    $('input', table.column(colIdx).footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
      table
        .column(colIdx)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.widthind {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

form {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-boardered" id="examples">
  <thead class="thead-dark">

    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>

      <th>Customer Name</th>

      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>

      <td>2PslfYy</td>

      <td>He-man </td>

      <td>good product 1</td>
    </tr>

    <thead class="thead-dark excludeAction" style="background-color: !important;">
      <tr>

        <th colspan="50">

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>

        </th>

      </tr>

    </thead>

    <tr>

      <td>3lpnSrv</td>

      <td>Jhon Doe</td>

      <td>good product 2</td>
    </tr>

    <thead class="thead-dark excludeAction" style="background-color: !important;">
      <tr>

        <th colspan="50">

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>

        </th>

      </tr>

    </thead>

  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>

      <th>Customer Name</th>

      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are heading thead tags within the rows of the table.  This is not within the spec plus it won't work for Datatables.  Plus Datatables doesn't support colspan or rowspan within the tbody (rows).

After fixing the buttons the search still doesn't work because of the selector you have on this line:
`$('input', table.column(colIdx).footer()).on('keyup change', function () {`

This is affecting the global search also.  Compare your code to this example:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

A thead never goes inside tbody.

Check this [jsfiddle.net/nfycu6o5/1](http://jsfiddle.net/nfycu6o5/1/).

Correct html table:

```
<table class="table table-boardered" id="examples">
<thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>2PslfYy</td>
        <td>He-man </td>
        <td>good product 1</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3lpnSrv</td>
        <td>Jhon Doe</td>
        <td>good product 2</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your row is creating inside the thead element,  the search given in datatable will search from the tbody element instead of thead

Eg: when you type on the searchbox,  keyup event will trigger and find the results from table body and your table header always remains the same

```
<table class="table table-boardered" id="examples">
<thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>2PslfYy</td>
        <td>He-man </td>
        <td>good product 1</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3lpnSrv</td>
        <td>Jhon Doe</td>
        <td>good product 2</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```